# APEX_MAIL add image to content

Tags: oracle, image, base64, oracle-apex

I want to send mail with base64 image in HTML content but when I recieve that mail img tag is empty.

My code:

```
begin  
  apex_mail.send(  
        p_to => 'TO_MAIL',  
        p_from => 'FROM_MAIL',  
        p_body => 'Image test',  
        p_body_html => 'Image:<br /><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACQAAAAZCAAAAAB8j9M3AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAACeSURBVCjPxdIhFoAgDAbgRaLRyHE8gtFo9AZGjmDkGByNiLKJbjCfNv8GfMBjDNKHwB8oWKBY/4hCBywtRNRDHQkRHbMzDR2HW43uba5lLRKQri2ofVWcsjK+IHMMlJcjMwU59ahz4Srmw1EpcJR3rArqOUqLojz+1XyjONSKCIy8C1BdNfblw8coWgWVDAnRT1Q8hcimY4yJv3r8JTsvu7MOMQUglAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />',  
        p_subj => 'Image test'  
  );  
    apex_mail.push_queue();  
end;
```

Is this possible with Oracle apex_mail?

Answer (score 1):

Partially Yes, This functionality works in oracle apex.
But This image will not be supported in outlook, yahoo or gmail. So, if you open mail in outlook, yahoo or gmail then you will not be able to see the image.
Once you download this email as html then only you can see this image.